# DateField is not storing in Django

Tags: python, django

I am using SQLite on Django 1.4.5

models:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    exam_date = models.DateField()
```

forms:

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Score

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(ScoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['exam_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y')
          self.fields['exam_date'].initial = datetime.date.today()
          self.fields['exam_date'].input_formats = ['%d-%m-%Y']
```

The form is validating field correctly. But this field is not getting saved!!

I tried on command line some excerpts. There seems to be a problem at the model level actually.

My execution code:

```
>>> o = Score(exam_date = datetime.date.today())
>>> o.save()
>>> type(Score.objects.get(pk=).exam_date)
>>> NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code from forms and models is fine. But you have problems with your execution code. From your example there are no Integer provided for pk in yours Score query:

```
>>> o = Score(exam_date = datetime.date.today())
>>> o.save()
>>> type(Score.objects.get(pk=1).exam_date)
>>> <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Giving pk attribute some Integer, will return 'datetime.date' type for you.
And if it's just typo from question, let us know!

Comment: no! i deliberately didn't put a val in the description.. It would throw an Exception if I didnt put a pk val

Comment: Try to repeat your efforts with newest django (like 1.7).
Because there no problems with your code on it or there not enough evidences from your question.
It is my offer for you, good luck in resolving this problem!